# TYPO3 NEOS - FLUID and EXTBASE

Tags: typo3, neoscms

Is NEOS working like TYPO3 CMS (FLUID/EXTBASE) just with another layout ?
Can u add the same extension to NEOS and can u still make our own Backend Layouts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TYPO3 Neos](http://neos.typo3.org) is a completely new software, based on [TYPO3 Flow](http://flow.typo3.org). Conversion of extensions from Extbase to Flow/Neos should not be too hard, but you can't use the same code.

Comment: And there are no Backend Layouts. It's completely different, mostly based on frontend editing.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of TYPO3 Neos and TYPO3 CMS are completely different. While extra functionality for TYPO3 CMS is build as an extension (based on extbase and fluid) and directly integrated into the CMS, in TYPO3 Neos we have separate Flow packages which can be connected to TYPO3 Neos.

There are talks that in the future it will be possible to use flow packages for TYPO3 CMS, but nothing is decided yet.

Extbase extensions cannot be used in TYPO3 Neos. You have to rebuild the functionality as a Flow Package. However there is a similarity between Extbase and Flow, since Extbase is a backport of Flow. Fluid however can be used in Neos.